# Show there doesn't exist a 4-regular graph with 4 vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

I need to show why you can't have 4-regular graph with 4 vertices.

If I have a 4 regular graph with 4 vertices, then the sum of the degrees will be 16 since each degree is 4. That should equal to 2 times the number of edges. The number of edges in that graph is 8. So, they do equal to each other.

Am I missing something here?  Am I in the direct direction? Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Apparently, multiple edges are allowed. Are loops allowed as well?

Comment: No loops in this case.

Comment: So, you could start with a square (2-regular) and duplicate all edges?

Comment: no multiple edges either

Comment: Well, then how can a vertex have four neighbours if there are only three other vertices?

Comment: That's what I am trying to show.

Answer (score 1):

If we pick a vertex in a $4$-regular simple graph, by definition it has four neighbors.

[image]

This alone requires $5$ vertices, which is enough to imply it's impossible.

Except for the empty graph (which has no vertices nor edges), a $k$-regular graph must have $k+1$ or more vertices.

---

We can get it to work if we allow parallel edges, e.g.:

[image]

but not in a simple graph.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple edges are allowed then you *can* have a $4$-regular $4$-vertex graph: just take a cycle and double each edge. If the graph has to be simple then it's not possible because a simple graph can only have six edges and (as you say) you would need eight.

Comment: How do you know a simple graph can only have 6 edges?

Comment: @Lily:  each edge has to join a unique pair of vertices.  There are only ${4 \choose 2}=6$ pairs of vertices.  There are $6$ edges in $K_4$

Comment: 4 regular exceeds 6 pairs of vertices maximum, no loops or multiple edges

Comment: I got it. The maximum number of edges in a graph with n vertices is $ \ (n-1)n/2 $